# Laravel 4 URL::route

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I've got an controller function that deletes an account. It's basically an route. I've read the manual and there is

`URL::route('name of the route');`

But how could I do it in the ?

like input it in here:

```
<td><a class="btn btn-mini btn-danger" href="the url goes here"><i class="icon-trash icon-white"></i> Delete</a></td>
```

Comment: To make use of a "delete" route you can make use of a form with a _method: 'DELETE' attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to [explicitly 'name' the route](http://four.laravel.com/docs/routing#named-routes) if you want to call it by a route name:

```
Route::post('delete_character', array(
    'as'   => 'delete_character', // This is the route's name
    'uses' => 'AuthController@delete_character'
));
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, now I don't get errors, but still it doesn't seem to work. here is my function in AuthController@delete_character:
    `public function delete_character()
    {
      $player->delete();
      return View::make('index')->with('danger', 'You have successfully deleted your character!');
    }`

and when I click the button it just get an MethodNotAllowedHttpException :p

Comment: Hi core_m, I suggest you update your questions with more information so we can help you more effectively.

Answer (score 1):

if you define Route name you can use that in your blade :

define Route Name :

```
    Route::get('/admin/transfer/forms-list', [
        'as'   => 'transfer.formsList',
        'uses' => 'Website\TransferController@IndexTransferForms'
    ]);
```

now you can use that in your blade like this :

```
  <a href="{{URL::route('transfer.formsList')}}"  type="submit">
                        discard</a>
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are using Blade Template Engine,

Here is the solution:

```
<td><a class="btn btn-mini btn-danger" href="{{URL::route('controller.delete')}}"><i class="icon-trash icon-white"></i> Delete</a></td>
```

Comment: I get this error: `Unable to generate a URL for the named route "delete_character" as such route does not exist.`

I've used it like this: `<td><a class="btn btn-mini btn-danger" href="{{ URL::route('delete_character') }}"><i class="icon-trash icon-white"></i> Delete</a></td>`

also there is a route, but in a group:

`Route::post('delete_character', 'AuthController@delete_character');`